# Android file explorer to view files from a virtual server

Tags: android, open-source, file-management, networking, ldap

I am looking for an Android app, or an option I might have overlooked which allows me to browse the files on my server. I think the usage boils down to something along the lines of: I fill in LDAP user credentials, it authenticates with the LDAP server and shows me a list of folders where that user has access to. From there it needs to be able to open (PDF) files with another application assigned by the user.

I've been searching the Play Store and there is a whole legion of "file managers" and the like, but none I have found so far seems to provide the use mentioned above. Applications I tried are: Asus file manager, FX file manager, X-plore, Total commander and File commander.

The application needs to be open source or if not available at least a trustworthy source is required as the files the user will need to open contain customer orders.

Since it's my first time posting: If any clarification/addition to the question is desired please let me know and I'll try to update the question with the requested details.

Comment: I haven't seen a file manager dealing with LDAP (but maybe I've missed that feature because I didn't specifically look for it). To help you narrow down the list, might I suggest to check with my [corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman)? It has a section for network-capable file managers. As for searching Play, it allows a similar syntax as Google Search; so you could try `file-manager +ldap` – but you won't have much luck with the LDAP part (I just tried).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that list you made.

Comment: You're welcome! If you find something, don't hesitate to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little embarassing but that's life sometimes.. 
In hindsight the LAN/Network function provided by File Commander from Mobisystems (Not affiliated with) seems sufficient to my use case. Although it's likely plenty of other file manager applications provide similar features. See Izzy's list for a large array of (potential) alternatives.

To explore the files on the server using File Commander:

1. Install the File Commander app from playstore
2. Open de application
3. Select Local network from the menu
4. Click the add button on the top right side of the screen (+ button)
5. Enter the credentials
6. After authentication you'll find yourself in your network environment.

Comment: If you ever come back, please accept this, your own answer. Doing so will help others who read the question in the future. Thanks & upvote